# how replace text in ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

hi  have created a plugin for ckeditor .i am  converting selected text to uppercase or lowercase.

i have implemented it as

```
 var elementNode = editor.getSelection().getStartElement();
    var selectedText=editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
    var nodeHtml=elementNode.getHtml();
    alert(nodeHtml);
    alert(selectedText);
    nodeHtml.replace(selectedText,selectedText.toUpperCase());
    alert(nodeHtml);
```

i want to replace this text with its uppercase or lowercase version.
 replace method is nor working .
Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a jquery replaceWith function. This will do exactly what you want

```
$('#myElement').replaceWith(myValue);
```

myElement is selecter to select element. replaceWith will assign new value to myElement.

Comment: i want to replace  a portion of string with uppercase/lowercase version.

Comment: Then use $('#myElement').replaceWith(selectedText.toUpperCase());

Comment: can any one tell me how can i get index of curser in ckeditor?